# How to create a new Outlook email for every row of Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use an Excel sheet to populate an Outlook email draft and have every new row create a new email. I'm trying to achieve this using the openpyxl library.
The Excel file looks something like this.
[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTkkr.jpg)

I've tried to iterate over each row using list comprehension but the results are pretty much the same, I get one email created with the first row of data and but the rest of the information is not used. The only way I can use the information now is to change the row_offset number by myself, but obviously that doesn't work for doing many rows.

## I get the information from the Excel file using the following function

def get_info():

```
loc = "Excel_file_location.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(loc)

info = []
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
ws = wb.active
```

## Get data starting at row 2. Possible issue here?

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    for cell in row:
        info.append(str(cell.value))
return info
```

data = get_info()

## Text body of email with Excel file data

text = "Hello, {1}! Work order #{0} is complete".format(data[0], data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTkkr.jpg))

## Create email function

def Emailer(text1, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = recipient
mail.Subject = subject
mail.HtmlBody = text1
mail.Display(False)
```

Afterwards I would call on the Emailer function using something like

Emailer(text, "Completed WO {0} | {1}".format(data[0], data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTkkr.jpg)), data[2])

But I'm stumped on how to make this function work separately for every row of an Excel sheet. As of now it will only keep doing writing the same email over and over again without reading the rest of the rows.

Comment: `row_offset=1` looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to wrap every row into an object, and push the objects into the list `info` like so:

```
class Recipient():
    def __init__(self, w_order, name, email):
        self.w_order = w_order
        self.name = name
        self.email = email


def get_info():

    loc = "Excel_file_location.xlsx"
    wb = load_workbook(loc)

    info = []
    ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
    ws = wb.active

    for row in range(2, 5):
        rec = Recipient("", "", "")
        for col in range(ord('A'), ord('D')):
            if chr(col) == 'A':
                rec.w_order = ws[chr(col) + str(row)].value
            elif chr(col) == 'B':
                rec.name = ws[chr(col) + str(row)].value
            elif chr(col) == 'C':
                rec.email = ws[chr(col) + str(row)].value

        info.append(rec)


    return info
```

From there on you could access the information from `get_info()` in your mail function in a loop like so:

```
def Emailer(text1, subject, recipient): 

    import win32com.client as win3

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text1
    mail.Display(False)

data = get_info()


for i in range(0, len(data)):
    Emailer(text, "Completed WO {0} | {1}".format(data[i].w_order, data[i].name), data[i].email)
```

Comment: This seems to work, looks like this is the proper way to do it! Thanks a lot!